# BooFuzz UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: fuzzing, boofuzz

I am trying to fuzz a FTP server. After a few attempts (exactly 20) the boofuzz crashes when sending the following fuzzed string:

```
'USER %\xfe\xf0%\x00\xff\r\n'
```

Boofuzz crashed with the following error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

My fuzzing script contains the following lines:

> s_initialize("user")
>
> s_static("USER")
>
> s_delim(" ", fuzzable=False)
>
> s_string(u"user", encoding="utf-8")
>
> s_static("\r\n")

How can I deal with that UnicodeDecodeError?

Comment: Not sure if you're still working on this, but if so please post the full stack trace so we can see where the exception is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The string primitive is currently a bit... primitive. I would recommend filing an issue on the Github project as you may have found a bug.

Edit: For a quick fix, I would switch to ascii to get the fuzzer running. If you post the stack trace, I'd be happy to look further.